# React Native - Passing state to another screen

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native

so i want to pass a piece of state to a screen. when i console.log it, it is perfectly fine but when i update the state it does not dynamically update.

my home screen

```
useEffect(() => {
        // SNAPSHOT USER DATA
        db.collection("users").doc(currentUserUID)
        .onSnapshot((doc) => {
            setUserData(doc.data());
        });
    }, [])
```

than i pass it into

```
<FlatList
                    horizontal
                    style={{ marginBottom: 40 }}
                    data={trackscreenData.ModulePbs1}
                    showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
                    keyExtractor={(item) => item.TrackId}
                    renderItem={({ item }) => {
                        return (
                            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
                                navigation.navigate('Module', {
                                    TrackId: item.TrackId,
                                    userData: userData,
                                });
                            }}>
```

and than on my 'Module' screen i import te state

```
export const ModuleScreen = ({navigation, route}) => {
const userData = route.params.userData;
} console.log(userData)
return()
```

so when i update my state it updates on my homescreen but not in my Module screen.

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Pass userData as params in route it doesn't make userData in Modulescreen changed if userData updated from Homescreen.

if you want to do this, you need to use State Management.

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm that the Flatlist is getting the updated data. For that put a console and make sure you were receiving the update inside the renderItem. If not try to add [extraData](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#extradata) property. Also if you are interested, go through the [React Native Firebase doc](https://rnfirebase.io/firestore/usage-with-flatlists#main).